# Axios returning undefined when trying to obtain an image link

Tags: node.js, axios

So, I have this simple axios script which is supposed to get bitcoin's image using the coingecko API.

```
const axios = require("axios");

async function test() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`
    );
    console.log(data.image);
}

test();
```

Although, when I run it, it just returns undefined.
Whenever I try to print data, it returns this:
[image: data]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json). You probably want `data[0].image` given your `data` appears to be an array

Comment: it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting data as an array not an object
Inside data it is at 0th index.you check inside data[0] and not inside data.
So answer will be `data[0].image`

```js
const axios = require("axios");

async function test() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`
    );
    console.log(data[0].image);
}

test();
```